# Find matching value in table based on a column value

Tags: r

I have a table which looks like:

```
[1,] 1 6 8 0.09457250 0.09457250 0.09457450 0.09457250 0.094572200 0.094572200
[2,] 1 3 7 0.04620798 0.04620798 0.04620998 0.04620798 0.046207681 0.046207681
[3,] 2 5 4 0.00160710 0.00160710 0.00160710 0.00160710 0.001607281 0.001607281
[4,] 6 6 8 0.09457250 0.09457250 0.09457450 0.09457250 0.094572200 0.094572200
[5,] 7 3 7 0.04620798 0.04620798 0.04620998 0.04620798 0.046207681 0.046207681
[6,] 12 5 4 0.00160710 0.00160710 0.00160710 0.00160710 0.001607281 0.001607281

[1,] 0.0945722 0.0945722 0.0945722 0.5171163 0.5171163 0.5171168 0.5171168
[2,] 0.9078313 0.5171163 0.5171163 0.5171163 0.4969045 0.4969050 0.4969050
[3,] 0.0016076 0.0016076 0.0016076 0.0016076 0.0016078 0.0016083 0.0016083
[4,] 0.0945722 0.0945722 0.0945722 0.5171163 0.5171163 0.5171168 0.5171168
[5,] 0.9078313 0.5171163 0.5171163 0.5171163 0.4969045 0.4969050 0.4969050
[6,] 0.0016076 0.0016076 0.0016076 0.0016076 0.0016078 0.0016083 0.0016083

[1,] 0.5171168 1.7740327 1.7740327 1.3879578 1.0062008 1.0062010 1.0062010
[2,] 0.4969050 0.4969109 0.4969109 0.4969050 0.4969050 0.4969050 1.0062010
[3,] 0.0016083 0.0016142 0.0016142 0.0016083 0.0016083 0.0016083 0.0016073
[4,] 0.5171168 1.7740327 1.7740327 1.3879578 1.0062008 1.0062010 1.0062010
[5,] 0.4969050 0.4969109 0.4969109 0.4969050 0.4969050 0.4969050 1.0062010
[6,] 0.0016083 0.0016142 0.0016142 0.0016083 0.0016083 0.0016083 0.0016073
```

For calculation purposes the first 3 columns can be neglected. But the first column stores a important information. If the value is 12 it means start at column 12 (if first 3 columns are not counted) or a column 15 if they are taken to account and look within that row (row 6 in this case) to the right and left (of row6,column 12) for the stretch of the values which are within a 10e-5 (plus or minus) value. It is important notes down the result as

```
column1 column2 column3 StartofStretch End of Stretch
12       5       4       1               20
```

where column 1,2,3 are the original first 3 columns. It would be important that it is robust to the number coming sometime later/earlier in the sequence (in the 1e5 tolerance)
To solve this problem I previously tried

```
f <- function(x){
  v <- x[4:length(x)]
  m <- which(v == v[x[1]] )
  return(c(start=min(m),stop=max(m)))
}
q <-cbind(p[,1:3],t(apply(p,1,f)))
```

However this does not consider the tolerance I talked about and it does not necessarily account if the number comes up after the stretch ends ( in a case that there is a stretch around column 12 or so of 2 to the right and left and then the same number comes up 7 or 8 or so columns right of the stretch this method would just count the the extremes when such a value is observed.

EDIT

So my small scale data set is

```
    t                                                                  
[1,] 1 23 20 0.008352330 0.008352572 0.008352330 0.008352330 0.008351730
[2,] 1 17 28 0.020770380 0.020770622 0.020770380 0.020770380 0.020769780
[3,] 1  4 12 0.006003570 0.006003812 0.006003570 0.006003570 0.006002970
[4,] 1 11 13 0.005008098 0.005008340 0.005008518 0.005008518 0.005007918
[5,] 1  3 10 0.006530800 0.006531042 0.006530800 0.006530800 0.006531300
[6,] 1 19 22 0.003711100 0.003711342 0.003711100 0.003711100 0.00371160

the output of lukeA's script  
         t       lower upper    expedected lower   expectupper
    [1,] 1 23 20     1     1         1                5
    [2,] 1 17 28     1     5         1                4
    [3,] 1  4 12     1     4         1                5
    [4,] 1 11 13     1     2          1               5
    [5,] 1  3 10     1     5          1               5
    [6,] 1 19 22     1     4         1               5
```

which is not true as in row 3 (to illustrate) the difference between columns 7 and 8 is -6times10to power of minus 7 which should then be in the range....what did i misunderstand?
Also in row 1 if the sensitivity is to the 4 decimal place then column3 and4 (or 1 and 2 if you dont count the first three as in the output) should be the same?

Comment: could somebody indicate whats not clear?

Comment: What is the question? What are you trying to do? What are the important notes? What  have you tried? Then will be easier to answer something

Comment: It is really about pattern matchign from column 12 (in this case)

Comment: please see th eupdated question lisitng what Ive tried

Comment: Well you answer one of the three questions, now there are just 2 left, specially the second one. We are not wizards and "about pattern matching" doesn't explain much, and the fact that what you have tried is which is confusing

Comment: Furthermore, I doubt it increases willingness to help you to find that you have received answers to all your 20 previous questions, but accepted none of them. Read [**about Stackoverflow**](http://stackoverflow.com/about), [**what to do when someone answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), [about **voting**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and [**about accepting answers**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235), and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick & dirty one (`mat` holds your table):

```
f <- function(row, tol=4) {
  a <- unname(signif(mat[row, -(1:3)], tol))
  i <- mat[row, 1]
  l <- which(!a == a[i])
  upper <- l[which(l > i)[1]] - 1
  lower <- tail(l[which(l < i)], 1) + 1
  if (is.na(upper)) upper <- length(a)
  if (length(lower) == 0) lower <- 1
  return(c(lower=lower, upper=upper))
}
(res <- t(mapply(f, 1:nrow(mat))))
#      lower upper
# [1,]     1     9
# [2,]     1     6
# [3,]     1     6
# [4,]     1     9
# [5,]     7     7
# [6,]     7    14
cbind(mat[, 1:3], res)
```

Comment: that is great @lukeA. Coul I ask whether it detects in both direction or only forward from the the volumn indicated by the first column?#

Comment: @user3069326 both. ps: You might want to use `(res <- t(mapply(f, 1:nrow(mat), 3)))` to get the desired tolerance.

Comment: could you tell me where to add this in your oce..or briefly update it..i woudl be very gratefu

Comment: hey @lukeA  if i try your code I get an error in p[row,-(1:3)]:subscript out of bounds..is there somewhere where you define the number of cilumns or of rows which the matrix is allowed to have?

Comment: @user3069326 no there is no definition. It worked with your example data.

Comment: okay @lukeA, just to maek sure the tolerance in your answer is equal to 10to the power minus 5 (plus and minus). How could I change it?

Comment: @user3069326 `tol` contains the accuracy in terms of decimals places.

Comment: Hey @lukeA I edited my answer..it would be great if you could have a brief look

Comment: @user3069326 What output would you expect for lower/upper in row 1 to 6?

Comment: Hey @lukeA i edited the answer...for me the cases just dont make sense when there is no change to the fifth decimal place ...just take row 1 as example between column 1 and column2 there is a no change to the 6th decimal place but then your script returns lower 1 upper 1

Comment: I edited my answer to include the expected value...do you see what I mean?@lukeA